# Convert PDF to ePub

Tags: pdf, epub, file-conversion

I would like to convert a PDF file to ePub format for reading it on an iPhone.

Is there an online/desktop tool that will allow me to do that?

Comment: There *are* tools that will do this. Unfortunately, **none** of them will do it well. The PDF conversion process throws away all information not related to displaying the contained text on a page that is exactly 8.5*11. Getting a PDF to reflow nicely for any other page size is a nightmare of manual reformatting. PDF should ONLY BE USED FOR TAKING DOCUMENTS TO **PRINT** (sorry this is a pet-peeve of mine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quality of conversion will depend on how complicated and how well structured your PDF is but give the online service **[2EPUB](http://www.2epub.com/)** a try.

Answer (score 5):

Don't bother with the paid solutions, Calibre is free and open source. Just used this to turn a bunch of docs to epub for ipads

http://osxdaily.com/2010/08/12/convert-to-epub/

so easy to do it's great.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/). It has excellent support for converting pdf files to epub format.

Answer (score 2):

[Epub2Go](http://www.epub2go.com/Web/default.aspx) allows conversion of PDF files from your desktop as well as on the web into ePub format.