# How can I convert PDF ebooks to Epub format?

Tags: macos, pdf, epub

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert PDF to ePub](https://superuser.com/questions/168863/convert-pdf-to-epub)

I have some digital books in PDF format but now I want to read them on my iPhone so I have to convert them to ePub format, could anyone please tell me how to do that?

Comment: -1, question does not show research effort.

Answer (score 2):

Want Convert Pdf format to Epub format?
try using Calibre Converter.
Calibre is free and open source. Just used this to turn a bunch of docs to epub for ipads
http://osxdaily.com/2010/08/12/convert-to-epub/

Comment: I have been using Calibre for a few weeks now, and I find that the Table of Contents that are produced are unusable.